# z-index issue - getting a NESTED element over & above the modal overlay attached to body

Tags: html, css, overlay, css-position, z-index

I have the following html, what i need is that the section tag having the text in it should come over & above the overlay. Simply giving it higher z-index doesnt help.
Please note that the below html is just a skeleton of what i have, there are more nested elements and content, however i just provided the basic minimum what was needed.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

plunk - http://plnkr.co/edit/sxC2D3nAgg7JJZjbOX0f?p=preview

HTML:

```
    <body>
     <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
       <header>
        <div class="searchwrapper">
         <section>
           This is the text to be over & above overlay
         </section>
        </div>
       </header>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="overlay"></div>    
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
    .wrapper {position:relative; }
.overlay {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 1005; background: #000; opacity: .5;}
.content {position:absolute; z-index:2;}
header{position:absolute; z-index:15;}
.searchwrapper {position:absolute;}
section {z-index:1006; color:#fff;background:blue;}
.modal {width:100px; height:100px; background:#fff; position:absolute; right:0; top:40px; z-index:1010;}
```

Answer (score 0):

With all z-index, you have to have an explicit position declaration.

Try this:

```
section {
    z-index: 1006;
    color: #fff;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {position:relative;}
.overlay {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 1005;  background: #000; opacity: .5;}
.content {position:absolute;}
header{position:absolute;}
.searchwrapper {position:absolute;z-index:1006}
section {color:#fff;background:blue;}
```

Wat u did is right.. the wrong u did is.. Give it for the parent of section tag instead of child tag.. u ll get it..

Answer (score 0):

**Give the z-index of ur overlay in -ve**

```
.overlay {

 z-index: -1;

}
```

or

**increase the z-index of wrapper**

```
.wrapper {
position: relative;
z-index: 999999;
}
```

Comment: Well, its not working...at least in my code. But in plunkr it seems to work.

Comment: How would i know what you have done in your code , you provided the code i tried to fix it . :)

Comment: Yeah, I completely agree, sorry about that, I think I missed something in plunk, am just going to update the post.